# Output looped print to file in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate random phone numbers. I'd like to output it into a file, but it only gets output once. I've already tried other code but it didn't work either.

```
import random

a = input(":")
b = input("amount:")
b = int(b)
c = "0123456789"
d = input("prefix:")
d = int(d)
for file in range(b):
    a_file = open("Phone.txt", "w")
    print(
        a,
        d,
        random.choice(c),
        random.choice(c),
        random.choice(c),
        random.choice(c),
        random.choice(c),
        random.choice(c),
        random.choice(c),
        random.choice(c),
        random.choice(c),
        random.choice(c),
        random.choice(c),
        sep="",
        file=a_file)
    a_file.close()

# var o = print...
#file = open("Phone.txt", "w")
#file_data = repr(o)
#file.write(repr(o))
#file.close
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code

```
a_file = open("Phone.txt", "a")
```

Instead of

```
a_file = open("Phone.txt", "w")
```

`a` is for appending, `w` is rewriting the file.